# How to code an activity handling a bundle from a specific activity alone?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I've an activity which receives a bundle from one activity via intent and it works fine. But the same activity is needed to be called by another activity which does not deliver a bundle to it, and hence the app crashes throwing a null pointer exception expecting a bundle on every intent. So how to code the activity to looks for a bundle only when called from a particular activity. Or is there another way of passing data which is sender specific?

Comment: Show code and usely you just need to check if the bundle is not set to null before using it.

Comment: You can add a null check for the bundle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the `Bundle` is not `null` before accessing it:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle != null) {
   // do whatever you wanted to do here
}
```

Further more if in future you want any other Activity also to send some other value or data type to the same `Activity` you can do one more check inside the `null` check:

```
if (bundle != null) {
    if(bundle.getString("key_specific_to_previous_activity") != null){
       // do something for that specific activity
    }
}
```